# UTF16 conversion failing with utfcpp

Tags: c++, utfcpp

I have this bit of code below that I've written that uses [utfcpp](http://utfcpp.sourceforge.net/) to convert from a utf16 encoded file to a utf8 string.

I think I must be using it improperly, because the result isnt changing.  The `utf8content` variable comes out with null characters (`\0`) every other character exactly like the uft16 that I put into it.

```
//get file content
string utf8content;
std::ifstream ifs(path);
vector<unsigned short> utf16line((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(ifs)), std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());

//convert
if(!utf8::is_valid(utf16line.begin(), utf16line.end())){
    utf8::utf16to8(utf16line.begin(), utf16line.end(), back_inserter(utf8content));
}
```

I found the location in the library that is doing the append, it treats everything in the first octet the same, whereas my thought is that it should handle 0's differently.

From [checked.h](https://github.com/ledger/utfcpp/blob/master/source/utf8/checked.h) here is the append method (line 106).  This is called by `utf16to8` (line 202). Notice that I added first part of the if, so that it skips the null chars in an attempt to fix the problem.

```
template <typename octet_iterator>
octet_iterator append(uint32_t cp, octet_iterator result)
{
    if (!utf8::internal::is_code_point_valid(cp))
        throw invalid_code_point(cp);

    if(cp < 0x01)                 //<===I added this line and..
        *(result++);              //<===I added this line
    else if (cp < 0x80)                        // one octet
        *(result++) = static_cast<uint8_t>(cp);
    else if (cp < 0x800) {                // two octets
        *(result++) = static_cast<uint8_t>((cp >> 6)            | 0xc0);
        *(result++) = static_cast<uint8_t>((cp & 0x3f)          | 0x80);
    }
    else if (cp < 0x10000) {              // three octets
        *(result++) = static_cast<uint8_t>((cp >> 12)           | 0xe0);
        *(result++) = static_cast<uint8_t>(((cp >> 6) & 0x3f)   | 0x80);
        *(result++) = static_cast<uint8_t>((cp & 0x3f)          | 0x80);
    }
    else {                                // four octets
        *(result++) = static_cast<uint8_t>((cp >> 18)           | 0xf0);
        *(result++) = static_cast<uint8_t>(((cp >> 12) & 0x3f)  | 0x80);
        *(result++) = static_cast<uint8_t>(((cp >> 6) & 0x3f)   | 0x80);
        *(result++) = static_cast<uint8_t>((cp & 0x3f)          | 0x80);
    }
    return result;
}
```

I cant imagine that this is the solution however, simply removing the null chars from the string and why wouldnt the library have found this?  So clearly I'm doing something wrong.

So, my question is, what is wrong with the way that I'm implementing my utfcpp in the first bit of code?  Is there some type conversion that I've done wrong?

My content is a UTF16 encoded xml file.  It seems to truncate the results at the first null character.

Comment: Are you sure you're not calling the append function with chars? Does the value in `cp` ever get higher than 255? Also, are you sure that the `std::istreambuf_iterator<char>` is OK? Shouldn't it be `<uint16_t>`?

Comment: @MrLister `cp` is 65535 or lower.  As for the `char` vs `uint16_t` I'll test it!

Comment: @MrLister `std::istreambuf_iterator<uint16_t>` doesnt compile.  Cant cast.

Comment: You're not skipping the null characters, you're leaving an unwritten byte in your output.

Comment: @MarkRansom, Not quite sure i follow.

Comment: `(*result++);` increments the output iterator without doing anything to it. To skip the input without outputting anything just use the empty statement `;`.

Comment: @MarkRansom Ok, I see.  Still that is my change, not the original library.  I dont understand how the library could have such a bug in it.

Comment: You need to remove your edit to `append()`. It is a bad edit, and it is unnecessary anyway. The input is a UTF-32 codepoint that has already been decoded from the original UTF-16 input, null byte octets and all, so there is no need to handle null values in the encoding of the codepoint to UTF-8. U+0000 is a valid codepoint to encode to UTF-8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::ifstream` reads the file in 8bit `char` units.  UTF-16 uses 16bit units instead.  So if you want to read the file and fill your vector with proper UTF-16 units, then use `std::wifstream` instead (or `std::basic_ifstream<char16_t>` or equivalent if `wchar_t` is not 16-bit on your platform).

And do no call `utf8::is_valid()` here. It expects UTF-8 input but you have UTF-16 input instead.

If `sizeof(wchar_t)` is 2:

```
std::wifstream ifs(path);
std::istreambuf_iterator<wchar_t> ifs_begin(ifs), ifs_end;
std::wstring utf16content(ifs_begin, ifs_end);
std::string utf8content;

try {
    utf8::utf16to8(utf16content.begin(), utf16content.end(), std::back_inserter(utf8content));
}
catch (const utf8::invalid_utf16 &) {
    // bad UTF-16 data!
}
```

Otherwise:

```
// if char16_t is not available, use unit16_t or unsigned short instead

std::basic_ifstream<char16_t> ifs(path);
std::istreambuf_iterator<char16_t> ifs_begin(ifs), ifs_end;
std::basic_string<char16_t> utf16content(ifs_begin, ifs_end);
std::string utf8content;

try {
    utf8::utf16to8(utf16content.begin(), utf16content.end(), std::back_inserter(utf8content));
}
catch (const utf8::invalid_utf16 &) {
    // bad UTF-16 data!
}
```

Comment: I'm getting `Error: expression must have a class type` for `utf16content.begin()` for each option here.  I havent yet determined what wchar_t size is yet, but my platform is windows 32bit.

Comment: `wchar_t` is 16bit on Windows, and `std::wstring` has a `begin()` method.

Comment: Ok, so I'm using the first option. And I see that wstring has a begin option, but it must be the way that `utf16content` is being declared.  I still get the `expression must have a class type` error. :(

Comment: I tested it and am having a similar problem when using `std::istreambuf_iterator` directly in the `std::wstring` constructor. But if I declare separate `std::istreambuf_iterator` variables, it works fine! I updated my answer to show that.

Comment: Excellent, thank you very much.  They really should allow multiple upvotes. ;)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is where you're reading the file:

```
vector<unsigned short> utf16line((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(ifs)), std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());
```

This line is taking a `char` iterator and using it to fill a vector one byte at a time. You're essentially casting each byte instead of reading two bytes at a time.

This is breaking each UTF-16 entity into two pieces, and for much of your input one of those two pieces will be a null byte.

Comment: I'm sure this is the correct answer.  It makes perfect sense now.  The only piece i'm missing then is how to read the file two bites at a time.

Comment: Use `std::wifstream` instead of `std::ifstream`, (or `std::basic_ifstream<char16_t>` or equivilent if `wchar_t` is not 16-bit on your platform).

Comment: @RemyLebeau I don't think that will be sufficient. You'll just be moving the point where the bytes are cast.

Comment: @MarkRansom: I was in the middle of re-writting my comment when you commented.  What do you think of the new comment?

Comment: @RemyLebeau, yes I think that would help.